# Can some one help me with this limit?

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=\frac{((a-n)nx-\tan x)\sin nx}{x^2} $ at $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Where $n$ is a non-zero real number and $f$ is continous at $x=0$, then $a$ is equal to?

I am aware of identity $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ But don't know how to use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\frac{((a-n)nx-\tan x)n}{x} . \frac{\sin nx}{nx}$$
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=((a-n)n-\frac{(\sin x)}{x.\cos (x) } )n. \frac{\sin nx}{nx}$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=((a-n)n-1)n=0$$
$$a=\frac{1}{n}+n$$

Hope it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using that around $0$ :
$$\sin(x)=x+o(x^2)$$
$$\tan(x)=x+o(x^2)$$
We get that around $0$ :
$$f(x)=\frac{((a-n)nx-\tan x)\sin nx}{x^2}=\frac{(anx-n^2x-x+o(x^2))(nx+o(x^2))}{x^2}\\=\frac{an^2x^2-n^3x^2-nx^2+o(x^2)}{x^2}\\=\frac{x^2(an^2-n^3-n+o(1))}{x^2}\\=an^2-n^3-n+o(1)$$

So $f$ is continuous in $0$ iff :
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)  =f(0)\iff an^2-n^3-n=0\iff a=\frac{n^3+n}{n^2}=\frac{n^2+1}n$$